# Imagick font converting is bad: svg to png

Tags: php, svg, imagick

I need to build an svg dynamically from PHP. After that I want to convert it to show it as a `.png`. I am using `Imagick` for this.

```
$this->pngBinary = new \Imagick();
$this->pngBinary->setBackgroundColor(new \ImagickPixel('transparent'));
$this->pngBinary->setfont(FONTS_PATH . 'courier.ttf');
$this->pngBinary->readImageBlob($this->svgContent);
$this->pngBinary->setImageFormat("png32");
$this->pngBinary->writeimage(BASE_PATH . 'xxx2.png');
```

When I am listing fonts by `$this->pngBinary->queryFonts();` Courier is listed.

The SVG output contains this:

```
<text style="font-size: 9px; fill:black; font-family: Courier" x="227" y="94">64</text>
```

On localhost, everything is works fine. The png is shows the numbers.

But on the debian box, it does not convert the numbers. There are little rectangles instead.

[image]

What could be the problem?

Sadly I have no access to the `Imagick` binaries and directories, only the PHP user has.

Comment: Those squares are usually indicative of encoding issues. Try replacing the ttf font for any other ttf font and see if it displays the same behavior.

Comment: I tired it without font, or with other fonts, and it is the same. And these are only numbers, not texts, so I think it is not an encoding problem.

Comment: Ok, it was a server setting. I told to our system administrator to set the proper font path in the environment variables, and that solved the problem!